# Is there a way to output the result of a "git blame" to a text file?

Tags: git, shell

I am running the `git blame` command on a large file and would like to see the results in a text file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. On the command line simply direct the output to your own file instead of `STDOUT`:

```
git blame source_file > blame_result_file
```

Comment: I just remembered I could do this right before you posted this lol. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

command line redirect which works for any command that prints to standard out:

git blame > output.txt

Comment: Note: you have to supply a filename: `usage: git blame [options] [rev-opts] [rev] [--] file`